# Initiate/Propose a SmartContract call using Safe Core SDK (gnosis)

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, gnosis-safe

I'm trying to initiate/propose a transaction using Safe Contract SDK (gnosis-safe), but I can not find any example where the SC method and parameters are specified in the transaction object.
The documentation is not very clear, I thing data and value should be filled with method signature and parameters.

If you have any example it will be great.
Thanks!

-- Doc from gnosis-safe

import { SafeTransactionDataPartial } from '@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk-types'

const safeTransactionData: SafeTransactionDataPartial = {
to,
data,
value,
operation, // Optional
safeTxGas, // Optional
baseGas, // Optional
gasPrice, // Optional
gasToken, // Optional
refundReceiver, // Optional
nonce // Optional
}
const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction({ safeTransactionData })

Answer (score 0):

The [transaction tutorial](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/tutorials/tutorial_tx_service_initiate_sign#fields-required-for-a-safe-transaction) does imply that the `data` field is the contract call. As you surmised, `value` is the gas token value being submitted with the transaction.

Both of these fields mirror the way all transactions work on EVM-compatible networks.

Once you have generated the calldata for the contract you want to interact with, you can add it to the `data` field. This generation is outside the direct scope of Safe - the proposed transaction simply executes the provided calldata - hence why the docs do not walk through that aspect.

If you're not familiar with generating EVM calldata, you should find a library in the language you're most comfortable with and refer to their documentation.